# Esconder a metade de um ícone em um Card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tenho esse código (Bootstrap 4):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-inverse card-primary text-xs-center">
            <div class="card-block">
                <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                    <p><h3>12,345</h3></p>
                    <footer>Texto de Exemplo</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria de usar um ícone do FontAwesome e deixar o ícone encostado no canto direito do card, e o resto do ícone ser invisível.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui vai uma base, agora é só ir ajustando conforme quiser utilizar, cores, tamanhos, posições, etc...

```css
.icon-card {
    font-size: 102px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    right: -1px;
    width: 41px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-inverse card-primary text-xs-center">
            <div class="card-block">
                <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                    <p><h3>12,345</h3></p>
                    <div class="icon-card">
                        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                    </div>  
                    <footer>Texto de Exemplo</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1. Eu incluiria um `pointer-events:none` na regra do `.icon-card` p/ não ficar aparecendo aquele cursor de seleção de texto ao passar o mouse sobre o ícone.

Comment: Hum quebradinho http://i.imgur.com/9SCTphI.png

Comment: Não entendi...??? @KingRider

Answer (score 2):

Muito simples usar font awesome, eu utilizo bastante dele faço grafico online a ferramenta morris.js e existe pronto chama Microsoft PowerBI, bom vamos lá segue abaixo de exemplo:

Página Font Awesome do código exemplo de funcionamento:
http://fontawesome.io/examples/

Necessidade carregar CDN e apenas CSS por causa fontes para web:
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-inverse card-primary text-xs-center">
            <div class="card-block">
                <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                    <p><h3>
                      <i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
                      12,345</h3></p>
                    <footer>Texto de Exemplo</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```